# Vue property or method is not defined when using non-minify version

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I created a simple Vue example to show the name 'John' using inline template but get the following error instead:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "name" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
```

However if I use the minify version:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

The code works with the word 'John' print out and no error is shown. Is this some sort of bug or I'm not using Vue properly?

```js
Vue.component('profilecontent', {});

var content = new Vue({
  el: '#profile-content-wrapper',
  data: {
    name: "John",
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.2/dist/vue.js"></script>

<!-- Minify version works
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
-->

<div id="profile-content-wrapper">
  <profilecontent inline-template>
    <div>
      <div>{{name}}</div>
    </div>
  </profilecontent>
</div>
```

Comment: Any references to data inside of inline templates are scoped to the component with that `inline-template` attribute. So the error you're receiving makes sense: your `profilecontent` component doesn't have a `name` property even though you are referring to it in its template. But, like you, I am confused about why your code works with the minified version of Vue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that using the minified version of Vue fixes the bug, it's that the un-minified version shows warnings when you're doing something that's probably incorrect, and the minified version suppresses these warnings.

The way you're using `inline-template` means that Vue wants to look for your `name` variable on the profilecontent component, instead of on the main app.  Strictly speaking you should be passing `name` to that component as a prop; this eliminates the warning even in the unminified development mode:

```js
Vue.component('profilecontent', {props: ['name']});

var content = new Vue({
  el: '#profile-content-wrapper',
  data: {
    name: "John",
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.2/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="profile-content-wrapper">
  <profilecontent inline-template :name="name">
    <div>
      <div>{{name}}</div>
    </div>
  </profilecontent>
</div>
```

(That said, I'm honestly not certain why the `name` variable is managing to fall through to the component when the warnings are suppressed; variable scope inside an inline-template is supposed to be to the component, not its parent.)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `<slot></slot>` to compose your component i.e: putting other element inside it like :

```js
Vue.component('profilecontent', {
  template: `<h1><slot></slot></h1>`
});

var content = new Vue({
  el: '#profile-content-wrapper',
  data() {
    return {
      name: "John",
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.2/dist/vue.js"></script>

<!-- Minify version works
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
-->

<div id="profile-content-wrapper">
  <profilecontent>
    <div>
      <div>{{name}}</div>
    </div>
  </profilecontent>
</div>
```

if you're working with inline template you could put that `name` property inside the data object of that component like :

```js
Vue.component('profilecontent', {
   data() {
    return {
      name: "John",
    }
  }
});

var content = new Vue({
  el: '#profile-content-wrapper',
 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.2/dist/vue.js"></script>

<!-- Minify version works
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
-->

<div id="profile-content-wrapper">
  <profilecontent inline-template>
    <div>
      <div>{{name}}</div>
    </div>
  </profilecontent>
</div>
```